# Android Save the Custom class obj in SQlite DB using SUGAR ORM?

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

Below is my Jason Response and for this I have two model class which extends SugarOrm

```
{
    "id": "300",
    "location": "59",
    "location_name": "new bel road ",
    "cushy_lat": "13.03135560",
    "cushy_lng": "77.57323110",
    "tags": "[Baba, Nimit]",
    "description": "Nimit baba",
    "emoticon": "3",
    "lat": "13.02891950",
    "lng": "77.57151030",
    "media_url": "http:\/\/dev.cushy.com\/useruploads\/196821e0c5de0b28b96048d556fc3934.JPEG",
    "user": {
        "id": "1",
        "fullname": "Joseph Ranjan",
        "email": "sjranjan@sjranjan.com",
        "total_cushy": "7",
        "followers_count": "1",
        "following_count": "1",
        "am_i_following": 1,
        "is_he_following": 0,
        "user_dp": "http:\/\/cushy.com\/userdp\/89aefdba9be455761b8992d8f813328e.jpeg"
    },
    "distance": "0.49",
    "cushy_time": "yesterday",
    "last_navigation": "yesterday",
    "is_liked": 0,
    "is_navigated": 0,
    "is_wishlist": 0
}
```

My Main model class

```
 @SerializedName("ids")
private String CUSHYID;
@SerializedName("location")
private String location;
@SerializedName("location_name")
private String location_name;
@SerializedName("cushy_lat")
private String cushy_lat;
@SerializedName("cushy_lng")
private String cushy_lng;
@SerializedName("tags")
private ArrayList<String> tags;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;
@SerializedName("emoticon")
private String emoticon;
@SerializedName("lat")
private String lat;
@SerializedName("lng")
private String lng;
@SerializedName("media_url")
private String media_url;

@SerializedName("user")
private Users user;

@SerializedName("distance")
private String distance;
@SerializedName("cushy_time")
private String cushy_time;
@SerializedName("last_navigation")
private String last_navigation;
@SerializedName("is_liked")
private String is_liked;
@SerializedName("is_navigated")
private String is_navigated;
@SerializedName("is_wishlist")
private String is_wishlist;

public CUSHYRECORD() {
}

public String getCUSHYID() {
    return CUSHYID;
}

public void setCUSHYID(String CUSHYID) {
    this.CUSHYID = CUSHYID;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getLocation_name() {
    return location_name;
}

public void setLocation_name(String location_name) {
    this.location_name = location_name;
}

public String getCushy_lat() {
    return cushy_lat;
}

public void setCushy_lat(String cushy_lat) {
    this.cushy_lat = cushy_lat;
}

public String getCushy_lng() {
    return cushy_lng;
}

public void setCushy_lng(String cushy_lng) {
    this.cushy_lng = cushy_lng;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(ArrayList<String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getEmoticon() {
    return emoticon;
}

public void setEmoticon(String emoticon) {
    this.emoticon = emoticon;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(String lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public String getMedia_url() {
    return media_url;
}

public void setMedia_url(String media_url) {
    this.media_url = media_url;
}

public Users getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Users user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(String distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getCushy_time() {
    return cushy_time;
}

public void setCushy_time(String cushy_time) {
    this.cushy_time = cushy_time;
}

public String getLast_navigation() {
    return last_navigation;
}

public void setLast_navigation(String last_navigation) {
    this.last_navigation = last_navigation;
}

public String getIs_liked() {
    return is_liked;
}

public void setIs_liked(String is_liked) {
    this.is_liked = is_liked;
}

public String getIs_navigated() {
    return is_navigated;
}

public void setIs_navigated(String is_navigated) {
    this.is_navigated = is_navigated;
}

public String getIs_wishlist() {
    return is_wishlist;
}

public void setIs_wishlist(String is_wishlist) {
    this.is_wishlist = is_wishlist;
}
```

as you can see in response there is one more inner object called "user". So i create a separate model class for the same

```
public class Users extends SugarRecord{

public Users(){

}

private String cushyid;
@SerializedName("ids")
private String userid;
@SerializedName("fullname")
private String fullname;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("total_cushy")
private String total_cushy;
@SerializedName("followers_count")
private String followers_count;

@SerializedName("following_count")
private String following_count;
@SerializedName("am_i_following")
private String am_i_following;
@SerializedName("is_he_following")
private String is_he_following;
@SerializedName("user_dp")
private String user_dp;

public String getCushyid() {
    return cushyid;
}

public void setCushyid(String cushyid) {
    this.cushyid = cushyid;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getFullname() {
    return fullname;
}

public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getTotal_cushy() {
    return total_cushy;
}

public void setTotal_cushy(String total_cushy) {
    this.total_cushy = total_cushy;
}

public String getFollowers_count() {
    return followers_count;
}

public void setFollowers_count(String followers_count) {
    this.followers_count = followers_count;
}

public String getFollowing_count() {
    return following_count;
}

public void setFollowing_count(String following_count) {
    this.following_count = following_count;
}

public String getAm_i_following() {
    return am_i_following;
}

public void setAm_i_following(String am_i_following) {
    this.am_i_following = am_i_following;
}

public String getIs_he_following() {
    return is_he_following;
}

public void setIs_he_following(String is_he_following) {
    this.is_he_following = is_he_following;
}

public String getUser_dp() {
    return user_dp;
}

public void setUser_dp(String user_dp) {
    this.user_dp = user_dp;
}
```

}

Now this User class is a custom class so the value is not getting stored in the DB. My coulmn is getting created but no value in this. Can anyone please suggest me how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Read http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

You have a default constructor for Users:

```
public Users(){
}
```

BUT you have **NO** actual constructor (so no database will be created):

```
public Users(){
String cushyid, 
String userid,
String fullname,
String email,
String total_cushy,
String followers_count,
String following_count,
String am_i_following,
String is_he_following,
String user_dp ){
this.cushyid = cushyid;
...
    }
```